# How to import a trained model into keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I trained a model with *scikit-learn* and saved it with joblib to the disk.

`joblib.dump(model, 'new_file_address')`

I want to know is there anyway to load this trained model into *keras*?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `joblib`'s `load()` method for the same and pass the path of the saved model as an argument. Here's an implementation for the same:

```
# Saving a model
joblib.dump(ml_model, 'path/to/saved_model.pkl')

# Loading a model
ml_model = joblib.load('path/to/saved_model.pkl')
```